# OS Error 10060 - Issue with launching the browser using Selenium Python using vscode

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

**Code Used:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://google.com/")
```

**Issue :**

> Exception managing chrome: error sending request URL
> (https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/known-good-versions-with-downloads.json):error
> trying to connect: tcp connect error: A connection on attempt failed
> because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
> time, or established connection failed because connected host has
> failed to respond. (os error 10060)

Seems it's an proxy set-up issue. Unfortunately, I'm unable to set a new proxy due to company restrictions where I need to update this change in selenium webdriver such that it does not hit the URL mentioned in the issue.

I tried to reinstall the selenium drivers.

Need to know where to update the changes in selenium or vscode to point the URL correct instead of re-directing to URL mentioned in issue.